# Add year function boolean and replace 3-letter month with its month number in an array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, regex, replace, preg-replace-callback

**Background information:**

- The log file is copied and read out at regular intervals.
- Log file lines do not have a year specification.
- Months are continuous.
- Before January is always the previous year.

If January lines do not appear in the log file, then it is only about the current year. Example:

- 2023 mar,
- 2023 apr,
- 2023 may,
- 2023 jun

If January occurs one or more times in the month cycle, then the current year is from the beginning of the last occurrence (January). Example:

- 2021 nov,
- 2021 dec,
- 2021 dec
- 2022 jan, // new year
- 2022 jan,
- 2022 feb,
- ...
- 2022 dec,
- 2023 jan, // new year, last jan = actual year
- 2023 jan,
- 2023 feb,
- ...

**Code:**

Recognize which year it is based on the 3-letters and lines and add the correct year to each line.

```php
$arr = [
    // without first Dec, Jan and Jan lines:
    // all subsequent lines are the current year
    "Dec 23 21:37:56 hello",
    "Jan 12 02:08:23 hello",
    "Jan 16 17:34:33 hello",
    "Feb  4 12:21:09 hello",
    "Mar 19 17:07:26 hello",
    "Apr  1 00:00:03 hello",
    "Apr 12 23:07:39 hello",
    "May 21 04:09:34 hello",
    "Jun  7 23:34:56 hello",
    "Jul  1 14:45:34 hello",
    "Aug 13 11:37:23 hello",
    "Sep 29 07:36:03 hello",
    "Oct 30 09:01:00 hello",
    "Nov 10 11:00:03 hello",
    "Dec 25 21:47:51 hello"
];
```

Create a function to find the years.

```php
function setYear()
{
    global $arr, $y;
    $first = explode(' ', $arr[array_key_first($arr)]);
    
    // if the 1st line doesn't start with Jan, then it's the previous year.
    if (!in_array('01', $first)) {
        $y = date("Y", strtotime("-1 year"));
    } else {
        $y = date("Y");
    }
    return $y;
}
```

Convert date year and month integer

```php
$arr = preg_replace_callback(
    '/^(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s/',
    function ($matches) {
        global $y;
        $yy = setYear($y);
        return date($yy . ' m d', strtotime($matches[0] . ' ' . date("Y"))) . ' ';
    },
    $arr
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Unexpected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2022 12 23 21:37:56 hello
    [1] => 2022 01 12 02:08:23 hello
    [2] => 2022 01 16 17:34:33 hello
    [3] => 2022 02 04 12:21:09 hello
    [4] => 2022 03 19 17:07:26 hello
    // ...
    [9] => 2022 11 10 11:00:03 hello
    [10] => 2022 12 25 21:47:51 hello
)
```

Expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2023 12 23 21:37:56 hello
    [1] => 2022 01 12 02:08:23 hello
    [2] => 2022 01 16 17:34:33 hello
    [3] => 2022 02 04 12:21:09 hello
    [4] => 2022 03 19 17:07:26 hello
    // ...
    [9] => 2022 11 10 11:00:03 hello
    [10] => 2022 12 25 21:47:51 hello
)
```

Comment: The global cariable will stay the same?

Comment: `setYear()` doesn't have any parameters, why are you calling it with `$y` as the argument?

Comment: The comment says you're checking for `Jan` as the first word of the line. So why are you searching the whole array for `01`?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? It doesn't seem like you've really made an attempt to solve it, since your code doesn't come even close to what you want. It seems like you just posted some related code in order to get us to do it for you.

Comment: I don't know if that is a fair assessment @Barmar.  While the coding attempt is flawed, it is not just word salad, is looks like a reasonable attempt to do the described task.  I just hope that the array is 100% guaranteed to contain a `Jan` entry so that the year-change flag can be toggled.

Comment: `// if the 1st line doesn't start with Jan, then it's the previous year.` - seems a bit arbitrary. Your example data set does not contain a _continuous_ set of months - so is it even a given, that January will _always_ be in there? If your example above was Dec-Feb-Jun-Dec instead - then Feb and Jun would still belong into 2023.

Comment: @Barmar, it may be that for some my question and description does not correspond to their level. I'm sorry. As a beginner, I may need time to acquire the expected programming skills. I try to archive logfiles filtered and cleaned categorically as json file. For this I build a cronjob file in php... I often get stuck, turn around in circles and get stuck... trail and error...

Comment: @0stone0, what is a cariable?

Comment: @CBroe, I wanted to keep the description short. It can also happen that there are no entries for a certain month.

Comment: If January must not necessarily be present - then your approach of explicitly checking for that, does not make too much sense to begin with. So this information _is_ absolutely essential to your question. "Shortness" must not win over _clarity_.

Comment: Or did you try to say that January will _always_ be present, but the _other_ months might or might not be? Even _that_ is not absolutely clear right now.

Comment: @CBroe, yes you are right. there is no month without activity. the logiles files are synced at regular intervals. then it is processed with another cronjob. the log files lines do not contain a year specification. The transition from the past year to the current one is recognized by January. I revised the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `static` variable instead of bringing global variables into scope with `global`.  The `static` keyword will ensure that the previous iterations' declaration is retained and is accessible.  If `Jan` is encountered or was encountered before, set the flag as `true`.  Until the flag is set to `true`, subtract 1 year from the date's year.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PfkAR))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/^([a-z]{3}) +\d+/i',
        function($m) {
            static $encounteredJan = false;
            $encounteredJan = $encounteredJan || $m[1] === 'Jan';
            return date('Y m d', strtotime($m[0] . ($encounteredJan ? '' : ' -1 year')));
        },
        $arr
    )
);
```

---

If you cannot rely on Jan existing in the dataset, then (assuming you never need to jump more than one year forward), just check if the current month is less than the last encountered month.  If, say, going from Sep to Apr (10 to 4), then you can safely assume that the year should be increased/incremented.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JBvtv))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/^([a-z]{3}) +\d+/i',
        function($m) {
            static $lastMonthInt = 0;
            static $year = null;
            $year ??= date('Y', strtotime('-1 year'));
            $currentMonthInt = date('n', strtotime($m[1]));
            if ($currentMonthInt < $lastMonthInt) {
                ++$year;
            }
            $lastMonthInt = $currentMonthInt;
            return "$year " . date('m d', strtotime($m[0]));
        },
        $arr
    )
);
```

---

Final edit:

To ensure that the highest generated year is the current year, use `array_reverse()` to process the data from latest entry to the earliest entry.  Compare the standardized timestamp expression against the previous timestamp. When the current stamp is greater than the last, decrement the year.  When finished processing, call `array_reverse()` on the result to return it to its original order.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rQXWW))

```
var_export(
    array_reverse(
        preg_replace_callback(
            '/^[a-z]{3} +\d+ \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/i',
            function($m) {
                static $lastStamp = null;
                static $year = null;
                $year ??= date('Y');
                $currentStamp = date('m d H:i:s', strtotime($m[0]));
                if ($currentStamp > ($lastStamp ?? $currentStamp)) {
                    --$year;
                }
                $lastStamp = $currentStamp;
                return "$year $currentStamp";
            },
            array_reverse($arr)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: how complex it all is. I'm learning something about that again. I am very grateful to you. I didn't know the "static variable" yet. I have to read into it.

Comment: I realized the previous year is taken even if "jan" isn't present on the line. I don't have the knowledge to edit/supplement your suggestion. I've edited the question a bit. Here the [link](https://3v4l.org/L93Kc) what i mean

Comment: I try around all the time. I can't make sense of it. it's beyond my logic: [link](https://3v4l.org/8YHB9#v8.2.2)

Comment: @Cem a new snippet has been added.

Comment: I realized I was premature. What happens if Jan occurs more times, or does not occur at all? I edited my question to be a little more detailed and added some background information. Forgive me for my chaotic nature. This proves again that I still have a lot to learn. Do you accept small jobs for payment?

Comment: Is there something about my updated answer that does not satisfy?

Comment: Hello. Thanks. The highest year is always the current year. In your example, there are dates in the future, or only 2022. If there is no transition month, all months should be 2023. I've tried around, but can't find a solution.

Comment: @Cem I have added a final edit.

Comment: it looks perfect I will test the code on Monday. I am very grateful to you. thanks to you I'm moving forward. I own you something. LG from Vienna.

Comment: hi, I modified the code and see that it works as expected. The next thing I have to do: put the json files with the right content in the right directories (year/month). I need support here because my knowledge is no longer sufficient here. Is it possible to help me here for a fee? thanks

Comment: I am very expensive for hire.  You will be better off trying to be a developer yourself, then posting a new question when you are stuck.  Believe in yourself, do the work, learn as you go.  If you do not do these things, you will not grow.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty and motivation – That motivates me.